# Mocking completeExceptionally with RestAssured (spring-mock-mvc) call to Controller (in Java)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mocking, rest-assured, completable-future

Good morning,

I've struggled with this for a day and I cannot get my head around what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any help!

I have a test method:

```
  @Test
  public void shouldReturnConflictWhenPlayerAlreadyRegistered()
  {
    CompletableFuture<Void> failFlow = new CompletableFuture<>();
    failFlow.completeExceptionally(new CompletionException(new PlayerNameAlreadyRegisteredException(
        "Player already registered")));

    when(mockedWhackAMoleService.register(any(String.class))).thenReturn(failFlow);

    given().params("name", "dan")
           .standaloneSetup(registrationResource)
           .when()
           .post("/players")
           .then()
           .statusCode(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value());
  }
```

The premise is simple: when the POST to `/players` is executed (which calls `register` on the `RegistrationResource` class) the mocked `mockedWhackAMoleService.register` method returns a CompletableFuture which completes exceptionally. Stepping through the test with the debugger shows the call to `mockedWhackAMoleService.register(...)` does indeed trigger the `exceptionally` branch in the `RegistrationResource` class.

For completeness, here's the code to the class under test `RegistrationResource`:

```
  @PostMapping
  public CompletionStage<ResponseEntity<Void>> register(@RequestBody String name)
  {
    logger.info("Registering player {}", name);
    return whackAMoleService.register(name).thenApply(ResponseEntity::ok).exceptionally(t -> {
      logger.error(t.getCause().getMessage());
      if (t.getCause() instanceof PlayerNameAlreadyRegisteredException)
      {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
      }
      else
      {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
      }
    });
  }
```

If I run the server and POST to the `register` method on the `RegisterResource` and try to register the same player twice, I do receive a 409 response - as expected.

However, when running the test, `then().statusCode(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value())` fails, because it receives a 200, not the expected 409!

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks,
Dan